Normal operator with certain condition is self adjoint
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional complex vector space with inner product, and let $T\in L(V)$ be a normal linear operator such that $T^9=T^8$. Show that $T$ is a self-adjoint projection.

The condition $T^9=T^8$ implies $T^8(T-I)=0.$ This mean that $m_T(x),$ the minimal polynomial of $T$; divides $x^8(x-1)$ and is the product of different linear factors.
Now, clearly $m_T(x)\in\left\{ x, x-1, x(x-1)\right\}$
If $m_T(x)=x$, then $T=0$.
If $m_T(x)=x-1$, then $T=I$.
If $m_T(x)=x(x-1),$ then $T^2=T.$
In any of these three previous cases, $T$ is a projection.
So, the eigenvalues of $T$ are $0$ and $1$. Since $T$ is normal and has real eigenvalues, then $T$ is self-adjoint.
Is this solution correct?

For any  matrix $T$ we have $\ker T^*\oplus {\rm Im}\,T=\mathbb{C}^n$ and the subspaces are orthogonal. As $T$ is normal we have $\ker T^*=\ker T,$ i.e.
$$\ker T\oplus {\rm Im}\,T=\mathbb{C}^n$$ The linear transformation  $T:{\rm Im}\,T\to {\rm Im}\,T$ is injective, i.e. it is an isomorphism from ${\rm Im}\,T$ onto itself. The same holds for $T^8.$ As $TT^8=T^8$ the transformation $T$ acts as the identity on ${\rm Im}\,T.$ Moreover $T$ vanishes on $\ker T.$ Thus $T$ is the orthogonal projection onto ${\rm Im}\,T.$

Did you use the equivalent condition of normal operator, $||Tx||=||T^x||;$ in order to claim that $\ker T^=\ker T$?

Yes, I have used that identity.

Your answer is incomplete. You need to justify why the minimal polynomial of $T$ must be a product of distinct linear factors, when this is not true in case $T$ is just a general linear operator. Here you need to use the condition that $T$ is normal (and hence diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$), but this is not mentioned anywhere in your answer.
Alternatively, without using diagonalisability or minimal polynomial, you may proceed as follows. Since $T$ is normal and $T^8(I-T)=0$, we have
$$
(I-T^\ast)(T^\ast T)^8(I-T)
=(I-T^\ast)(T^\ast T)^8(I-T)
=(I-T^\ast)(T^\ast)^8T^8(I-T)=0.\tag{1}
$$
Now, using the normality of $T$ and the fact that $\forall A\in L(V),\,A^\ast A=0\implies A=0$ (because $\|Ax\|^2=\langle Ax,Ax\rangle=\langle x,A^\ast Ax\rangle=0$ for all vectors $x$), $(1)$ leads to the following sequence of inferences:
\begin{align*}
&(I-T^\ast)^\ast(T^\ast T)^8(I-T)=0\\
&\implies (T^\ast T)^4(I-T)=0\\
&\implies (I-T^\ast)(T^\ast T)^4(I-T)=0\\
&\implies (T^\ast T)^2(I-T)=0\\
&\implies (I-T^\ast)(T^\ast T)^2(I-T)=0\\
&\implies T^\ast T(I-T)=0\\
&\implies (I-T^\ast)T^\ast T(I-T)=0\\
&\implies (I-T^\ast)T^\ast T(I-T)=0\quad\text{and}\quad(I-T^\ast)TT^\ast (I-T)=0\\
&\implies T(I-T)=0\quad\text{and}\quad T^\ast (I-T)=0\\
&\implies T^2=T\quad\text{and}\quad T^\ast=T^\ast T\\
&\implies T^2=T\quad\text{and}\quad T=(T^\ast T)^\ast=T^\ast T=T^\ast.\\
\end{align*}
Therefore $T$ is a self-adjoint projection. Note that the proof above is still valid if $V$ is infinite-dimensional.
